# Get comma-separated string from CheckboxList HTML Helper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I got the following code from the internet for `CheckboxListFor` html helper extension. At the moment, in the `SelectedValues` it is returning a `List<string>` of selected values from the checkboxlist. I want to get a comma-separated string in `SelectedValues`.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve it?

Here is the code:

HTMLHelper extension:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Returns a checkbox for each of the provided <paramref name="items"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string listName, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var container = new TagBuilder("div");
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

            var cb = new TagBuilder("input");
            cb.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
            cb.MergeAttribute("name", listName);
            cb.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value ?? item.Text);
            if (item.Selected)
                cb.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");

            label.InnerHtml = cb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + item.Text;

            container.InnerHtml += label.ToString();
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(container.ToString());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCheckboxListWithDefaultValues(object defaultValues, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
    {
        var defaultValuesList = defaultValues as IEnumerable;

        if (defaultValuesList == null)
            return selectList;

        IEnumerable<string> values = from object value in defaultValuesList
                                     select Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        var selectedValues = new HashSet<string>(values, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var newSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        selectList.ForEach(item =>
        {
            item.Selected = (item.Value != null) ? selectedValues.Contains(item.Value) : selectedValues.Contains(item.Text);
            newSelectList.Add(item);
        });

        return newSelectList;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a checkbox for each of the provided <paramref name="items"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var listName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        items = GetCheckboxListWithDefaultValues(metaData.Model, items);
        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxList(listName, items, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

In the view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SelectedValues, Model.MySelectList)
```

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{        
      public SelectList MySelectList{ get; set; }

      public List<string> SelectedValues{ get; set; }

      //public string SelectedValues{ get; set; }   Can I get comma separated string here
}
```

*Note that I need comma separated string returned from the helper not after I got back list on the controller action.*

**Why I am trying to do this?:**

```
//Here in my model, I am getting `SelectedValues` which is a List<String>.
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
      //My code....
}
```

**In View**

```
//But I cannot save this list into RouteValueDictionary like:
var searchCriteria = new RouteValueDictionary();
searchCriteria["model.SelectedValues"] = Model.SelectedValues; // List<string> cannot be save here. That's why I needed comma separated string.
var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary();
viewDataDictionary["searchCriteria"] = searchCriteria;

@Html.Partial("_MyPagingView", Model.MyList, viewDataDictionary)
```

There is a whole mechanism inside the `_MyPagingView` which calls `Index` Action whenever next page is clicked. And to preserve the state of the search we need to keep our searched data inside `RouteValueDictionary`.

Comment: [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Where to put string.join? Note that I need comma separated string returned from the helper not after I got back the list.

Comment: You helper is generating a series of checkboxes with the same name. It can only post back and array or values. You need to generate the comma separated string on the server, or use javascript to build the string and update a hidden input before you post.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid you can use ``string.Join`` in the controller action

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am already using javascript and hidden value. I was just curious to find out if I can get it without extra javascript code.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid, No, but you could modify you helper to (1) generate the hidden input in addition to the checkboxes and set its initial value and (2) pass a comma separated string to the helper rather than `IEnumerable<string>` so you can strongly bind it to `public string SelectedValues { get; set; }` (but not really sure why you would want to do this)

Comment: @UsmanKhalid i am just curious why you want like that??

Comment: @UsmanKhalid, I'm curious too. (please tell me you not trying to store a comma separated string in a database to represent relational data)

Comment: What about `searchCriteria["model.CommaSeparatedValues"] = string.Join(", ", model.SelectedValues);` (2 separate properties). Another option would be to create a utility helper method that builds the correct values in a loop so `List<string> SelectedValues` will be correctly bound (no need for a separate string property)

Comment: I have already found the solution using javascript and hidden field. I was just curious if my Html Helper could return me the desired output. Anyhow thanks for your time and solutions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper method to add the`SelectedValues` to a`RouteValueDictionary`

```
public void AddRoutes(List<string> values, string propertyName, RouteValueDictionary dictionary)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++ )
    {
        string key = string.Format("{0}[{1}]", propertyName, i);
        dictionary[key] = values[i];
    }
}
```

and then use it as

```
var searchCriteria = new RouteValueDictionary();
AddRoutes(Model.SelectedValues, "SelectedValues", searchCriteria);
```

and avoid the need to create a hidden input and use javascript

Answer (score 0):

I prefer changing the code of your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public SelectList MySelectList{ get; set; }

    public List<string> SelectedValues { get; set; }

    public string SelectedString
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedValues == null) return "";
            return string.Join(",", SelectedValues);
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                SelectedValues = value.Split(',').ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the comma seperated string :

```
//In controller
var selected = model.SelectedString; 

//In view
searchCriteria["model.SelectedValues"] = Model.SelectedString;
```